# How to solve three quadratic differential equations in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, differential-equations

I've just started to use Python for scientific drawing to plot numerical solutions of differential equations. I know how to use modules to solve and plot single differential equations, but have no idea about systems of differential equation. How can I plot following coupled system?

My system of differential equation is:

`dw/dx=y`  and
`dy/dx=-a-3*H*y`  and
`dz/dx=-H*(1+z)`

that `a = 0.1`  and `H=sqrt((1+z)**3+w+u**2/(2*a))`

And my code is:

```
import numpy as N 
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model(w,y,z,x,H): 
    dwdx=y
    dydx=-a-3*H*y
    dzdx=-H*(1+z)
    a=0.1
    H=sqrt((1+z)**3+w+u**2/(2*a))
    return [w,y,z,H]   

z0=1100      #initial condition
w0=-2.26e-8
y0=-.38e-4
H0=36532.63
b=0
c=10000
x=N.arange(b,c,0.01)

y=odeint(model,y0,x)    #f=Function name that returns derivative values at requested y and t values as dydt = f(y,t) 
w=odeint(model,w0,x)
z=odeint(model,z0,x)

plt.plot(w,x)
plt.plot(y,x)
plt.plot(z,x)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

General purpose ODE integrators expect the dynamical system reduced to an abstract first order system. Such a system has a state vector space and the differential equation provides velocity vectors for that space. Here the state has 3 scalar components, which gives a 3D vector as state. If you want to use the components separately, the first step in the ODE function is to extract these components from the state vector, and the last step is to compose the return vector from the derivatives of the components in the correct order.

Also, you need to arrange the computation steps in order of dependence

```
def model(u,t): 
    w, y, z = u
    a=0.1
    H=sqrt((1+z)**3+w+u**2/(2*a))
    dwdx=y
    dydx=-a-3*H*y
    dzdx=-H*(1+z)
    return [dwdx, dydx, dzdx]
```

and then call the integrator once with the combined initial state

```
u0 = [ w0, y0, z0]
u = odeint(model, u0, x)

w,y,z = u.T
```

Please also check the arguments of the plot function, the general scheme is `plot(x,y)`.

Comment: And also change the order of the arguments in the plot commands.